# AWS SDK Java Version 2 - Is there an equivalent of S3ObjectSummary from version 1

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am using S3ObjectSummary previously in my code with version 1 and I am now migrating my code to SDK 2.20. What's the equivalent of S3ObjectSummary in SDK 2.20?

Comment: The v2 [S3Object](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/S3Object.html) class looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting `S3ObjectSummary` objects as a result of listing the objects in a bucket, then the equivalent should be `S3Object`, since [ListObjectsV2](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#listObjectsV2(software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request)) returns a [response](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Response.html) with a `List<S3Object>`.